# Why is a. Volume shader not working along with a glass BSDF shader?

Tags: node-editor, glass

I recently saw this video on youtube by Midge Sinnaeve. I think there was a lot to learn from there so just after finishing it I opened Blender and I tried to recreate what he was doing on min 54:30.

Thing is, my glass shader doesnt look like the one in the video at all. Before I add the volume shader everything is ok, I can see the reflexions on the surface, but, when I create a volume Suzane under the glass I can't see anything new. If I take the glass off I can see the volume monkey so I don't think the problem has anything to do with this one.

I attach photos so you can see what I mean.

This is what it should look like.
[image: Reference Suzane]

This is what mine is looking like.[image]

I've already done it a couple times so the node configuration should be alright

Solution: Make sure you set the max bounces for volumes (inside *Render Tab > Light Paths*) to more than 0.

Comment: I guess he also plugged a volume shader into the volume output to get the glass on top.

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193771/how-do-volume-shaders-interact-with-light/193774#193774

Comment: You need to add more light too

Comment: Please don't write solved as part of the title. Don't write the solution as part of the question. Use the answers section to write your own answer and mark it as accepted. Please read the [help] section to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

**There are two suzannes in the scene;**

One has a  simple *[glass shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/glass.html?#glass-bsdf)* with a *[solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier)* and is the "outer suzanne" as I'll call it.

The second is inside the first and has a volumetric material (the tree I used is below). Midge added a *[displace modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html#displace-modifier)* to this one to shrink it .

Suzanne 1 (Outer) should look as so with the solidify:

[image]

Modifier stack will be as follows:

[image]

Suzanne 2 (Inner) should be as shown below, just slightly smaller than the outer suzanne to avoid any intersections that will cause shading issues will the glass material:

[image]

modifiers for inner suzanne are as follows:

[image]

This is the volumetric material I used:

[image]

<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

The result is about as below, but any volumetric material could be used:

[image]

Comment: The problem was actually that I had set the max bounces for volumes to 0... However thanks for your answer!!

Comment: @IgnacioRM the solution I added was from Midges stream, however feel free to add your own answer below rather than editing your question with your answer. It is always ok to answer your own question :)